# Suma de valores en tablas y mostrar el resultado

Tags: mysql

Tengo una tabla MySQL, con Cedula cliente, Dueuda Inicial , Fecha y Abono Necesito hacer una consulta que sume todos los valores con un mismo id de la tabla y lo muestre en una nueva columna, en la fila de su id relacionado.

Tabla:

`CI`| `Deu_Inc`|`Fecha` |`Abonos`
`1` | `100.00` | `1-2-18`| `20`
`1` | `100.00` | `2-3-18`| `50`
`2` | `600.00` |`1-2-18` | `30`
`2` | `600.00` |`2-3-18` | `50`
`3` | `120.60` |`1-2-18` | `60`
`3` | `120.60` |`2-3-18` | `20`

Resultado deseado:

`CI` |`Deu_Inc` | `suma` | `Total`
`1` | `100.00`  | `70`  | `30`
`2` | `600.00`  | `80`  | `520`
`3` | `120.60`  | `80`  | `40.60`

Comment: no comprendo la ultima columna de tu resultado deseado la que se llama Total

Comment: buenas q me de el nuevo valor q debe el cliente. Ejemplo el cliente con cedula 1 debe $100, pero hizo dos abonos ($50 + $20) tonces la deuda actual seria ($30)

Comment: hecho @luis arce te dejé una respuesta

Comment: Gracias!!!  probando...

Comment: solo corrobora el nombre de las columnas ya que yo replique el ejercicio y coloque unos aproximados

Answer (score 1):

Siguiendo el planteamiento original del problema, te propongo la siguiente solución.

> 1.- Funciones de agregación `SUM()`
>   2.- `GROUP BY` para agrupación de columnas iguales

```
SELECT CI AS id, DeudaInicial, SUM(Abonos) AS suma,
(DeudaInicial) - (SUM(Abonos)) AS Total
FROM data
GROUP BY id;
+------+--------------+------+----------+
| id   | DeudaInicial | suma | Total    |
+------+--------------+------+----------+
|    1 | 100.00       | 70   | 30.00    |
|    2 | 600.00       | 80   | 520.00   |
|    3 | 120.60       | 80   | 40.60    |
+------+--------------+------+----------+
```

> 1. Si te fijas hago un `GROUP BY()` de la columna `CI` a la cual le puse un alias llamado `id`
> 2. Después resto la columna `DeudaInicial` menos la columna `SUM(Abonos)` para tener justo ahi el valor de la suma hecha al inicio
>      solicitada
> 3. El `group by()` lo hago para que aquello valores de la columna `CI` que tiene el alias `id` se agrupen por coincidencia y cuando haya
>      mas de uno no se muestren repetidos

**ACLARACIÓN**

Solo considera que yo use una tabla con el nombre data, tu debes poner el nombre de la tabla que estes usando

Answer (score 0):

Sería;

```
select CI, Deuda, sum(Abonos) `suma Abonos`, Deuda - sum(Abonos) as total 
from  `deudas`
group by CI
```

Ahora, tienes un problema en la tabla inicial, deberías separar las Deudas de los Abonos, algo como:

```
Deudas (CI, DeudaInicial)
Abonos (fk_CI, Fecha, Abono)
```

Y en este caso sería:

```
select D.CI, D.Deuda, sum(A.Abono) `suma Abonos`, D.Deuda - sum(A.Abono) as total 
from  `Deudas` D
Inner Join Abonos A on D.CI = A.fk_CI
group by D.CI
```

Comment: es verdar estoy repitiendo los campos. pues cuando creo el deudor le ponga la deuda. ahora como hago referencia a la tabla (cliente) campo (deuda Inicial)

Comment: la tabla cliente tiene Cedula, Nombre, Apellido , Deuda Inicial

Comment: Si tienes la tabla Cliente(Cedula, Nombre, Apellido , Deuda Inicial) y Abonos(fk_CI, Fecha, Abono) entonces la consulta quedaría algo como: select C.Cedula, C.`Deuda Inicial`, sum(A.Abono) `suma Abonos`, C.Deuda - sum(A.Abono) as total 
from  `Clientes` C
Inner Join Abonos A on C.Cedula = A.fk_CI
group by C.Cedula